# Using Firefox to download xml word doc. Image won't show

Tags: php, xml, image, ms-word

We have an xml word doc with image on title page that downloads correctly via ftp but the image is always missing if we try to download it via a link in an html page. We're using Firefox if that makes a difference. But we also tried it using Opera, with the same results.
Here's the link we're using:

```
$fileDest = './mydoc.xml';
<a type="msword" href="<?php echo $fileDest; ?>"><input type="button" value="Download Document" /></a>
```

Comment: a word doc as in Microsoft Word document?

Comment: Feels like the URL is being played with... have you checked to see if the missing image URL is what you expect post DL?

Comment: @Kasturi - Yes. It's a Microsoft 2003 Word Document saved as XML.
@qor72 - Let me look real quick...

Answer (score 0):

You serve different files via FTP and HTTP.